# Docusign - Populate tabs in envelope using REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I have created a template in DocuSign with a number of fields. I have also built an application that creates an envelope from that template and sends it using the REST API.

In that process I also would like to prepopulate those fields in the envelope document before sending to the first recipient. For achieving this I have looked at the update method for recipient tabs (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/update)

However when using the update method I need to have the tabId which is unique for each envelope. If I have 20 tabs in a document I have to fetch them all for getting the ID before doing an update. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The API must be able to determine the unique tab you wish to update, so a unique ID of some sort is required to do so. Note also tabs are for a specific recipient and you need to specify the page number as well.

Comment: Sure I understand that but is there no way to set unique Id in the template and use that to populate the document regardless of recipient?